# Unable to download PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to download PostgreSQL on my PC using but on the downloads page it is showing not supported.
[image]

And when I access the same page from another machine the download option is available for windows. This is my Windows config:

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't download it to another system and transfer it to mine due to USB port restrictions on other machines.

Please help

Comment: Try a different browser

Comment: Well, this worked. Thanks a ton @a_horse_with_no_name
weird it was not working in chrome

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what page you're on, but on [this official one](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) you can clearly see the download links for Windows versions.

Comment: I am on the same page and still on my PC it is showing not supported for windows

Comment: But the download links are populated by javascript.  They will show 'not supported' initially and then update after a few seconds (on my machine, with a slow connection), and if you have javascript disabled it will show 'not supported' forever.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did accepted cookies agreement.

Comment: This could have been a comment instead of an answer. It's very low quality.